# How to get columns names (fields) from SOLR using SOLRJ java client?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using solrj java client to read data from solr. below is the code snippet.

```
SolrClient Solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrlString+solrCoreName).build();

    // Preparing Solr query
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery(searchString);

    // Adding the field to be retrieved

    query.addField("*");
    query.setStart(start);
    query.setRows(rows);

    // Executing the query
    QueryResponse queryResponse = Solr.query(query);
    // Storing the results of the query
    SolrDocumentList docs = queryResponse.getResults();

    Solr.close();
```

I am getting data and sending back JSON as Output using SolrDocumentList.

My output is looks like below

```
[
{ "id":1,
   "name":"king",
   "address":"US"
},
{ "id":2,
   "name":"Jack",
   "address":"US"
}
]
```

But I need JSON output with column names along with data as separate attribute.

Any Help appreciated !

Comment: could you tell the JSON format you like to get, then it will be easy to understand.

Comment: columns: {"id", "name", "address" } ,data : [
{ "id":1,
   "name":"king",
   "address":"US"
},
{ "id":2,
   "name":"Jack",
   "address":"US"
}
]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your understanding of Solr(I may be wrong).

Solr is a collection of documents, not rows, rows will always have at least a predefined default value for every column but Solr document may or may not have value for every field defined in the schema depending on your indexing logic.
So, your output will always a **collection of documents** whereas each document is a collection of **key-value** pairs and only those keys will be returned for each document which you have specified value at the time of indexing.